# How to call a zend2 instance from other instance

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have 2 applications based on zend 2 framework which are deployed on the same server.
The app1 will call http requests to app2.
To improve performance, I want to bypass the http layer and create a zend 2 (app2) instance from code and then override its request and get the output response to a variable.

Below is my attempt:

```
public function callAPIDirect($url, $params, $method = 'GET')
{
    $app1_dir = getcwd();
    chdir(APP2_PATH);
    require APP2_PATH . '/init_autoloader.php';

    $app2Configuration = require APP2_PATH . '/config/application.config.php';
    $app2SmConfig = isset($app2Configuration['service_manager']) ? $app2Configuration['service_manager'] : array();
    $app2ServiceManager = new \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager(new \Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig($app2SmConfig));
    $app2ServiceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $app2Configuration);
    $app2ServiceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
    $app2ListenerFromAppConfig = isset($app2Configuration['listeners']) ? $app2Configuration['listeners'] : array();
    $app2Config = $app2ServiceManager->get('Config');
    $app2ListenerFromConfigService = isset($app2Config['listeners']) ? $app2Config['listeners'] : array();
    $app2Listeners = array_unique(array_merge($app2ListenerFromAppConfig, $conveyListenerFromConfigService));
    $app2 = $app2serviceManager->get('Application')->bootstrap($app2Listeners);

    $request = $app2->getRequest();
    $uri = new \Zend\Uri\Http($url);
    $queryString = $uri->getQuery();
    $request->setMethod($method);
    $request->setUri($uri);
    $request->setRequestUri($uri->getPath());

    $result = $app2->run();
    chdir($app1_dir);
    return $result;
}
```

But it seems the classes of Zend framework has been loaded in app1 and cannot be loaded in app2. Also the app2 could not be instanced properly.

Thanks

Comment: you can try running your other app using a command line route see what happens ...

Answer (score 2):

Do **NOT** try to achieve this with dispatching one ZF2 app within another. Zend\Mvc\Application is not stateless and will fail to do this.

The most convenient case is to use messaging between applications. You can use a message queue which containts a broker to dispatch messages back and forth. You send messages from app1 to the broker, where app2 will listen for it (and vice versa).

Two proven techniques for message queues are [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Messaging will make your two apps more scalable, better maintainable and uncouples them. These are much greater benefits than the (very minimal) speed gain of directly invoking php from one app to another.